# Producing a dictionary from a two lists companies

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists...one with advertising companies and the other with their clients...I am looking to have an output in dictionary format which shows me the advertising company with all of the clients they service.

```
{agency:{company1, company2 etc etc}}

Advertising Agency  Company
WPP Alienware
OMNICOM Alleghany Corporation
XYZ Allegheny Technologies
MEDIACOM    Allegis Group
XYZ Allen Organ Company
MEDIACOM    Allergan
WPP Alliance Rubber Company
OMNICOM Alliant Energy
XYZ Alliant Techsystems
MEDIACOM    Allied Insurance
WPP Allison Transmission
OMNICOM Allstate
XYZ Ally Financial
MEDIACOM    Aloha Air Cargo
```

Comment: That's nice. Do you ... have a question? (Specifically, an on-topic programming question, including your research and existing code, and explaining what's wrong with it, as per the how-to-ask pages of StackOverflow, rather than a "give me the code" request?)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
answer = defaultdict(set)
for agency, company in zip(agencies, companies):
    answer[agency].add(company)
```